# Nothing was returned from render. This usually means the return statement is missing

Tags: reactjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40Vei.png)

This error does not make sense to me when render is included

Comment: Use text for code, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `MemberCard` is missing a return statement

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A component should return a JSX, So you have to modify your code like this

```
const Test = ({data}) => {
  return data && data.check && data.check.map(el => {
      return el;
    })
}
```